# Why fillna does not work on string values?

Tags: string, numpy, dataframe, nan, fillna

I have a simple data like as below. I'm traying fill inside but does not work

frame like this;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

V1 = np.array([1,2,6, np.nan, 7, 1, np.NaN, 9,15])
V4 = np.array(['IT','IK', np.NaN, 'IK','IK','IK','IK','IT','IT'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'sl': V1,
               'departman': V4})

df
```

gives me:

```
    sl  departman
0   1.0 IT
1   2.0 IK
2   6.0 nan
3   NaN IK
4   7.0 IK
5   1.0 IK
6   NaN IK
7   9.0 IT
8   15.0IT
```

After I wrote this;

```
df['departman'].fillna(df.departman.mode()[0] )
```

Gives:

```
0     IT
1     IK
2    nan
3     IK
4     IK
5     IK
6     IK
7     IT
8     IT
Name: departman, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember this bugged me once in production. Your `np.nan` is converted to the string `"nan"` when you create the dataframe. See with:

```
df.loc[2, 'departman']
```

and you would get `'nan'`. You need to convert the string back to `np.nan` or use loc:

```
mask = df['departman'] == 'nan'
```

Output:

```
     sl departman
0   1.0        IT
1   2.0        IK
2   6.0        IK
3   NaN        IK
4   7.0        IK
5   1.0        IK
6   NaN        IK
7   9.0        IT
8  15.0        IT
df.loc[mask, 'departman'] = df.loc[~mask, 'departman'].mode()[0]
```